# Is it possible to add a reference to a website project in visual studio solution?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web

we have a solution that contains a website project (not a web application !!!) and anothe project, wcf.

In wcf project I need to use the functionality inside the website project.

I have no idea if it's possible to add a reference to the website project, since there are no actual DLLs I can point to, and website project does not appear in the list of projects when I click "Add reference" in my wcf project.

Is it even possible? We have tons of functionality in the website, some in ascx controls, some in xxxx.cs assemblies.

**Note**

I described the existing structure - please do not suggest to change it - it is not doable, business and technology limitations.

All I need is to know if it is possible to reference website project from another project inside the same solution.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is, just keep the solution file outside the web project, and add the projects on it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible, business requirements, please see my comments below.

Comment: @monstro Did you find a way?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you are going about it the wrong way, if you have common code which needs to be shared across 2 different projects then move that into it's own project (e.g. class library) and reference that instead.

Unless your website is a public facing API it wouldn't make sense to reference it from another solution - nor would it work in the way you want it to.

Comment: Please see my comment to a previous answer. This is not a new development, the project has been in development for almost 10 years :) There are thousands of pages, components, controls, assemblies and they all integrated with 3rd party CMS solution, embedded into the website.

Comment: @Sigourney_Weaver unfortunately that doesn't change the fact that what you are trying to do won't work. The website itself will eventually be compiled and generate a DLL but trying to load that & make sense of it would be a nightmare - my advice, write an API and expose the specific behaviour you need from your website to which the other systems can hook into.

Comment: you are right. That is what I WAS doing before trying to figure out that other option I am asking about. I was hoping there is a possibility to somehow reference a website and therefore gain access to all the functionality in it. I know it sounds weird, but this could actually be done IF it wasn't a website project, but a web application project, there the DLLs can be referenced.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you move common code to another assembly and refer it from both places!

Comment: I wish :) It is not possible - the website contains tons of code it's 10 years old integrated with Ektron's CMS 400 system, unfortunately not doable.